# Targeting dynamic elements in HTML widget with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use Javascript to retrieve elements from an HTML widget on the page. I can't just use the usual `document.getelementsbyclassname` etc. as the widget is treated as an embedded section of the page.

I have tried this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("widgetclassname")[0];
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

I've used that in the past for iframes but not for this. I'm getting this error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined*

I've tried adding a delay and moving around items in case it's a timing thing (trying to get things before it's loaded properly) but it made no difference.

I can't use ID instead of classname as the widget doesn't have one and I can't change that.

Comment: @Phrogz Yes I understand that, but I can't figure out why. Is it because it's not an actual iframe? I don't know a huge amount of Javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined` means *"Hey! `iframe` is undefined!"* Which means that your `getElementsByClassName()` is returning an empty node list.

We cannot help you further without a way of looking at the document you are trying to query. Are you using the developer tools to ensure that the `<iframe>` you want has that class on it? Exactly, no typos, no case changes?

Alternatively, you can try using:

```
// first iframe in the document
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

// third iframe in the document
var iframe = document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[2];
```

---

**Edit**: in response to our chat discussion, the problem is that the page is dynamically loading content, and the script you are trying to run is taking place before that content has been loaded.

A simple hack is to wait for the element you want to load and then run the code you want. For example:

```
document.title = "Search Results - AvenaGo"; 
var waitForHotel = setInterval(function(){ 
  var hotelName = document.querySelector('.hotel_page-hotel_name'); 
  if (hotelName) { 
    clearInterval(waitForHotel); 
    document.title = hotelName.textContent + ' - AvenaGo'; 
  } 
}, 100);
```

Every 100ms this code will run and check to see if an element with the class `hotel_page-hotel_name` has loaded yet. If it has, it will stop checking, and modify the title of the page based on the text in that element.

Comment: Thanks, but I can see there is definitely at least one item on the page with that class name, why is not recognising it? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Lyall If there is definitely an element with exactly that class name (with that exact capitalization) then I can imagine that either (a) the element you see is inside some other frame or document, or perhaps (b) the class name has been intentionally obfuscated with legal but non-visible Unicode characters (try copying/pasting from the developer tools?).

Comment: I can confirm that the element (div) I am targeting has the exact class name copied and pasted. Option (a) is a possibility, I will see how deep I can dig.

Comment: In Chrome: Right-click, Inspect Element, look at the bottom bar for a 'path' to the element.

Comment: Wait: a `div` has that class name? A div is not an iframe. A div does not have a `contentDocument`.

Comment: exactly, I need to know how to get to the elements inside the div. I was reading some posts where people were treating them like iframes and this was suggested (but obviously doesn't work as I've used it successfully for iframes). I plead ignorance about a div not being able to have a contentDocument (sorry). You'll be pleased to know I'm not a developer by trade...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149049/discussion-between-phrogz-and-lyall).